# Disable billing address in WooCommerce in checkout form when user select paypal payment method

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, payment

I am trying to disable the Billing fields in the checkout page when user selects the paypal payment method in WooCommerce wordpress theme.

Once the user complete the item selectionand comes to checkout page, if the user selects the paypal payment then the checkout form should not validate the billing fields if any other payment methos is selected then it should work as normal.

I searched alot but not able to find the clue. Please some one help to me on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* if you want the title of the payment method */
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'ts_refresh_payment_method' );
function ts_refresh_payment_method(){
$chosen_payment_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');  //Get the selected payment method

    // jQuery
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
var cpm = '<?php echo $chosen_payment_method; ?>';
if(cpm == "paypal"){
$(".woocommerce-billing-fields").hide();
}else{
$(".woocommerce-billing-fields").show();
}
            $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', 'input[name^="payment_method"]', function() {
//alert(this.value);
if(this.value == "paypal"){
$(".woocommerce-billing-fields").hide();
}else{
$(".woocommerce-billing-fields").show();
}

                $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
            });
alert($('body').trigger('update_checkout'));
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}

/*  */
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields','wpb_custom_billing_fields');
function wpb_custom_billing_fields( $fields = array() ) {
$chosen_payment_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');
if($chosen_payment_method == "paypal"){
$fields['billing_first_name']['required']= false;
$fields['billing_last_name']['required']= false;
$fields['billing_company']['required']  = false;
$fields['billing_email']['required']   = false;
$fields['billing_address_1']['required']= false;
$fields['billing_address_2']['required']= false;
$fields['billing_state']['required']   = false;
$fields['billing_city']['required']     = false;
$fields['billing_phone']['required']    = false;
$fields['billing_postcode']['required'] = false;
$fields['billing_country']['required']  = false;
}
return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at [PayPal for WooCommerce](http://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/).  It's free and it will allow you to enable PayPal Express Checkout instead of PayPal Standard, which flows a lot more nicely for people paying with PayPal.

Comment: Hi Thanks for you reply.. But your answer is not for my requirement. I want to disable the billing fields in the checkout forma when user selects the paypal payment method.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what I'm saying here.  Express Checkout essentially does that by skipping the checkout page altogether.

Comment: OP wants code to change/disable billing fields on payment method change.

Comment: Right, and my answer solves that problem by allowing you to skip the checkout page entirely.  It's actually a much better experience for the buyer, and it has been proven to increase conversion rates on websites by 20%+ when applied.  Only trying to help here.  Thanks for the neg. rep.